# How to find matching items in a list with a condition

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

the given data set :

```
P = {"alice": "R", "bob": "D", "carol": "D"}

V = {"alice": [True, True, False, True, None],
     "bob": [True, False, None, True, True],
     "carol": [False, False, False, None, None]}
```

I want to get the following result:

```
#[('alice', 'bob', 2), ('alice', 'carol', 1)]
```

we need to compare between "R" and "D" combinations and find the common values and return it.

Comment: how did you arrive at the output based and what do you mean by `R` and `D` combinations?

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = [['alice','bob',0],['alice','carol',0]]

for alice, bob, carol in zip(V.alice,V.bob,V.carol):
    if alice == bob:
        result[0][2] = result[0][2] + 1
    if alice == carol:
        result[1][2] = result[1][2] + 1
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The depicted `result` does not reflect the desired output of OP. Please add some details as well.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of methods to do this. This is the method I used,
First, you need to reverse  `p` because it is the easiest way as I think. I used the following code for that:

```
p_r = {}
for a, b in p.items():
    if p_r.get(b):
        p_r[b] += [a]
    else:
        p_r[b] = [a]
```

Then start comparing as usual:

```
k = []
for i in p_r['R']:
    for j in p_r['D']:
        s = [x == y and x is not None for x, y in zip(v[i], v[j])]
        k.append((i, j, s.count(True)))
```

Final code:

```
p = {"alice": "R", "bob": "D", "carol": "D"}

v = {"alice": [True, True, False, True, None],
     "bob": [True, False, None, True, True],
     "carol": [False, False, False, None, None]}

#  reverse dict p
p_r = {}
for a, b in p.items():
    if p_r.get(b):
        p_r[b] += [a]
    else:
        p_r[b] = [a]


k = []
for i in p_r['R']:
    for j in p_r['D']:
        s = [x == y and x is not None for x, y in zip(v[i], v[j])]
        k.append((i, j, s.count(True)))
        
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

first extract list of names for `R` and `D` using list comprehension

```
>>> [k for k,v in P.items() if v=='D']
['bob', 'carol']
>>>[k for k,v in P.items() if v=='R']
['alice']
```

Then find the combination from these list using `itertools.product`

```
>>>import itertools
>>>list(itertools.product([k for k,v in P.items() if v=='D'],[k for k,v in P.items() if v=='R']))
[('bob', 'alice'), ('carol', 'alice')]
```

Extract list of boolean values from the dictionary `V` for each combination

```
>>>first_comb = ('bob', 'alice')
>>>[V.get(person) for person in first_comb]
[[True, False, None, True, True], [True, True, False, True, None]]
```

get the sum of the results of logical-and(using `all()`) between list

```
>>>sum([all(elem) for elem in zip(*[V.get(person) for person in first_comb])])
2
```

combine all

```
import itertools
P = {"alice": "R", "bob": "D", "carol": "D"}
V = {"alice": [True, True, False, True, None],
     "bob": [True, False, None, True, True],
     "carol": [False, False, False, None, None]}
combinations = list(itertools.product([k for k,v in P.items() if v=='D'],[k for k,v in P.items() if v=='R']))

output = [(*item,sum([all(elem) for elem in zip(*[V.get(person) for person in item])])) for item in combinations]
print(output)
```

o/p:-

```
[('bob', 'alice', 2), ('carol', 'alice', 0)]
```